# VBA selecting option in HTML drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am pretty new to web-scraping and have limited html/js knowledge. I am trying to select a value in a drop down box. My code manages to loop over the options in the drop down list and recognizes the one I want, I just can't seem to select it.

code:

```
`For Each opt In ieDoc.getElementById("dealerCodeList").Options
        If opt.innerText = 9265 Then
            opt.Focus
            opt.Selected = True
            opt.setAttribute("selected") = "selected"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next`
```

The website I am using requires login access so I have attached screenshots. You can see it's the drop down list in the top left hand corner that I am trying to select a value for. Thanks in advance!

Website screenshot:

[image: website screenshot]

Comment: You can manually select yes. I am not really too sure how to check if theres js attached but I would assume that there is. If you look under the chosen results class. When you select a different value or hover a mouse over a value the class names for those li tags change.

Comment: Are there any other actions required like clicking on the down arrow first to show the list?

Comment: Try this `For Each opt In ieDoc.getElementById("dealerCodeList").getElementsByTagName("option"): If InStr(opt.innerText, "9265") > 0 Then opt.Selected = True: Exit For: Next opt`. Consider using a newline replacing `:`.

Comment: ieDoc.querySelector(".chosen-single").innerText = 9625   ? Don't really expect that to work tbh but give it a try.   For the record, we know ieDoc.querySelector("option[value=option6]").Selected = True doesn't work.

Comment: Tried ^ but no dice. My original code does evaluate the If opt.innerText = 9265 and executes the code inside... just doesn't work. And @QHarr yes you have to click the drop down first then click a value.

Comment: One more thing: did you put sufficient delay before executing the suggested lines?

Comment: I would consider switching to selenium basic at this point and mimic all the actions I would do manually.

Comment: Okay, try this now: `Set opts = ieDoc.getElementById("dealerCodeList"): opts.Click: For Each opt In opts.getElementsByTagName("option")`. Then the rest. Make sure to inform whether Is it a kendo grid?

Comment: @SIM that also did not work... Should I be somehow clicking on the drop down list then selecting... Also not sure what a kendo grid is/how to determine if it is one

Comment: It's hard to give any solution hypothetically. There are numerous ways things can be done but not without facing the real site. Check out [the link](http://search.wcad.org/Property-Search-Result?searchtext=319%20lizzie%20taylor) to see what a kendo grid is. The long grid containing `R016698` in it's first position.

Comment: under the chosen results list the list element for 9265 is <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">9265</li> before its clicked and after it's clicked it changes to <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="2" style="">9265</li> Not sure if that is significant? @SIM

Comment: @QHarr unfortunately I am limited to using vba by my employer

Comment: Btw, what happens when you try either of the suggested approaches? Does it throw any error? Anything insignificant that you haven't said?

Comment: @QHarr I just tried ieDoc.querySelector(".chosen-single").innerText = 9625 and it actually filled in the value however when I try to submit I get an error saying dealer required.

Comment: @SIM No errors, just nothing happens

Comment: Okay [check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949198/select-an-item-from-drop-down-in-ie). It might be relevant.